# guacamole not able to connect neither VNC nor RDP

Tags: guacamole

I setup a guacamole server on ubuntu 16.04 Tried to setup a connection to a vnc server on the same machine and always got errors. I tried with RealVNC Xvnc11 TIghtVNC, and even with RDP. no luck. The error messages on log files were:

```
Creation of WebSocket tunnel to guacd failed: Non-numeric character in element length.

Creation of WebSocket tunnel to guacd failed: java.net.ConnectException: 

Connection refused (Connection refused)

An internal error has occurred within the Guacamole server

not a valid RFB client

webSocketsHandshake: invalid client header
```

Any idea what could be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was saving the VNC connections settings on the GUACAMOLE PROXY PARAMETERS (GUACD). I set port 5901. Which is not the correct guacd port.

I left this empty and everything worked!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for RDP use RDP encryption select option
it worked for me.